# \\machine\sharedfolder (clickonce published folder via build script) can be visible only for the system which triggered the build

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce, build-process

I am triggering the build to publish the clickonce applicaiton in to a web location (\somewebsite.com\app\2014). That folder location is visible only for the system which i triggered the build. If see the particular web location from other system it is not exist and i am getting Error Code : 0x800004005 unspecified error. What went wrong? Some one please help me ?